# Java EE sessions: Can you store some attributes as non-persistent?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

Would I be able to store session variables in such a way that some of them can be brought back if the session is suspended while others are not?

Let's say I have 2 session variables named "A" and "B". I want "A" to be persisted and brought back if the session is ever suspended but I do not want "B" to ever be saved anywhere. I want it to be lost, for security related reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no. Besides, session normally live relatively short time (e.g. like 30 minutes) and all attributes will be gone after that.

However you can implement [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and store/restore your attributes when session is created and destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by suspended ? Do you mean serialized ? In that case take a look at the transient keyword.